# Xml invalid token error

Tags: android

I am getting an invalid token error on the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
```

On the eclipse IDE the error red 'x' is at the android:paddingLeft line. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hope you are closing the RelativeLayout.. I mean </RelativeLayout?

Comment: I tried using your layout code and it worked fine for me :)

Comment: @dtmc : What are the minimum and target SDK versions? Also are you using any of the Android support packages? If so, it could be a version issue which can be fixed by cleaning your project.

Comment: @Sushil Yes I am closing the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the project since it was a test. I was messing with the TextView of the xml before that, though. Thanks for the help though guys!

Comment: I ended up having the same problem on another test project. turns out after I click save, the error goes away. not sure why this is happening, though.